# Back and Next Navigation with Jquery

Tags: jquery, navigation

Im making a navigation control with back and forward links so that you advance or go back in a list of links. When you click on next it advances to the first page of the list but then stays there.
How I can set the visited link as active so that it advances sequentially i.e from 1 to 2 then from 2 to 3 etc...
Thanks for any help on this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('.next-button').click(function () {
               var $el = $('#nav li a.navSelected').removeClass('navSelected');
               var $next = $el.parent().next();
               if ($next.length == 0) $next = $('#nav li:first');
               $next.find('a.nav-button').addClass('navSelected');
               // Added window.location.href to follow the selected links href
               window.location.href = $next.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');
           });
           $('.prev-button').click(function () {
               var $el = $('#nav li a.navSelected').removeClass('navSelected');
               var $prev = $el.parent().prev();
               if ($prev.length == 0) $prev = $('#nav li:last');
               $prev.find('a.nav-button').addClass('navSelected');
               // Added window.location.href to follow the selected links href
               window.location.href = $prev.find('a.nav-button').attr('href');
           });
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="pagea.html"class="nav-button">A</a></li>
<li><a href="pageb.html" class="nav-button">B</a></li>
<li><a href="pagec.html" class="nav-button">C</a></li>
<li><a href="paged.html"class="nav-button">D</a></li>
<li><a href="pagef.html" class="nav-button">F</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="arrow-left" class="slide-right"><a href="#" class="prev-button"
title="Previous"><img src="images/arrow-left.png" alt="Left Arrow" width="25"
height="48"></a></div>
<div id="arrow-right" class="slide-left"><a href="#" class="next-button"
title="Next"><img src="images/arrow-right.png" alt="Right Arrow" width="25"
height="48"></a></div>
```

The answer has been provided by Steven in this Github:

https://github.com/Steven0213/Back_and_next_nav

Comment: One question do you also load a new page when you click on the next link? Or do you say hide the current text and show new text?

Comment: As soon you follow a href the page reloads. So your question would be rather...?

Comment: Steven: Im looking to load a different html page each time a person clicks on next. The code actually is working from an index to load the first html page of the list but then when I click next it just stays there and dont go to the second page. I think it has to do with adding the active tag to the actual page every time but i dont know how to do it, tried with some codes from here but not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created [this](https://github.com/Steven0213/Back_and_next_nav) fiddle for you. 
It's with Bootstrap and JQuery.
I don't know If you know Bootstrap and JQuery.
If you have any more question just ask.

[1](https://github.com/Steven0213/Back_and_next_nav):

```js
var ArrayOfPages = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];


var makeTheRightOneActiveWhenThePageStart = function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    for (var i = 0; i < ArrayOfPages.length; i++){
        var newUrl = ArrayOfPages[i] + '.html';
        if (url.indexOf(newUrl) > 1){
            var newI = i + 1;
            $("a:contains("+ newI + ")").parent().addClass('active');
        }   } };

var makeTheRightOneActive = function () {   var $selector = $(this);   var getClass = $selector.attr('class');   var getHTML = $selector.html();   var whatTheSetTrue;   switch (getClass){
      case 'prev':
          whatTheSetTrue = getTheRightOneActiveWhenPressPrevOrNext('prev',getHTML);
          break;
      case 'next':
          whatTheSetTrue = getTheRightOneActiveWhenPressPrevOrNext('next',getHTML);
          break;
      default:
          whatTheSetTrue = getTheRightOneActiveWhenPressPrevOrNext('',getHTML);
          break;   }   window.open(whatTheSetTrue + '.html', '_self', false) };

var getTheRightOneActiveWhenPressPrevOrNext = function (whatMethode,whichNumber) {
    var whatPageAreYouOn = $('.active').children().html();
    var whatCurrentPlaceAreYouOn = findAtWhichPlaceYouAreInTheArray(whatPageAreYouOn);
    var newPlace;
    switch (whatMethode){
        case 'next':
            newPlace = whatCurrentPlaceAreYouOn + 1;
            if (newPlace === 5){
                newPlace = 4;
            }
            break;
        case 'prev':
            newPlace = whatCurrentPlaceAreYouOn - 1;
            if (newPlace === -1){
                newPlace = 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            newPlace = findAtWhichPlaceYouAreInTheArray(whichNumber);
            break;
    }
    return ArrayOfPages[newPlace] };

var findAtWhichPlaceYouAreInTheArray = function (whatPageAreYouOn) {
    whatPageAreYouOn = parseInt(whatPageAreYouOn);
    return whatPageAreYouOn - 1; };

var init = function () {
    makeTheRightOneActiveWhenThePageStart();
    $('.container .pagination a').on('click',makeTheRightOneActive); }; $(document).ready(init());
```

```css
div.pageOne, div.pageTwo, div.pageThree, div.pageFour, div.pageFive{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#nav{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="pageOne">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas imperdiet, risus a rutrum eleifend, nulla lorem laoreet dolor, ut vehicula quam magna et est. Pellentesque egestas sem et ligula tincidunt finibus. Nullam a efficitur mi, eget rutrum
      dolor. Maecenas aliquet nibh quis vehicula gravida. Ut in finibus magna. Sed sagittis, velit ac cursus auctor, tortor dui mattis metus, sed commodo urna erat congue justo. Morbi porta nisi mattis lobortis aliquam. Phasellus nec nibh in ipsum scelerisque
      dignissim. Morbi id diam ut purus rhoncus suscipit placerat at libero. Curabitur quis eros maximus, pharetra urna eget, facilisis ex. Etiam commodo orci aliquet odio fermentum pulvinar. Duis auctor pellentesque condimentum. Duis ut nisi sem. Nulla
      in augue sed augue euismod feugiat in in nunc. Aliquam vel enim eros. Pellentesque leo dui, iaculis quis congue eu, ultrices id nisl.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pageTwo">
    <p>Cras vehicula ipsum ac eros porta dapibus. In eu ante varius, porta lectus sit amet, sagittis ipsum. Mauris congue velit mauris, condimentum sollicitudin mi luctus quis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent justo erat, facilisis id eleifend non, accumsan
      vel arcu. Sed id dui malesuada, vulputate velit sit amet, porta orci. Nam eu nunc eu erat accumsan ornare. Vivamus dui lacus, pharetra a bibendum nec, molestie non justo. Praesent at quam urna. Integer pharetra suscipit arcu, in sodales turpis mollis
      ut. Etiam placerat eget ante in congue.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pageThree">
    <p>Donec pretium ex a dolor luctus, eu malesuada metus condimentum. Aliquam consequat vestibulum massa, id iaculis magna aliquet malesuada. Nunc interdum turpis vitae metus feugiat, fringilla faucibus libero egestas. Donec tincidunt luctus gravida. Maecenas
      tincidunt interdum enim, vel consequat lacus auctor eu. Vestibulum metus lorem, posuere at gravida nec, lobortis vitae sapien. In auctor tempus pretium. Aliquam dictum urna ac aliquet imperdiet. Ut egestas eros et ante ornare, et pretium erat scelerisque.
      Donec libero nunc, posuere vitae massa non, tempus lacinia nisi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pageFour">
    <p>Nunc a nisl vitae tortor consequat ultrices. Suspendisse tincidunt rutrum ipsum in dictum. Proin tempus mi quis sollicitudin aliquam. Maecenas scelerisque id lectus et fermentum. Morbi dictum elit eu nisi convallis sagittis. In hac habitasse platea
      dictumst. In neque lectus, suscipit non quam sed, viverra viverra nisl. Donec at ex non velit vestibulum molestie a eget ex. In faucibus viverra purus, nec dapibus diam feugiat eu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
      per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pageFive">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et commodo sapien. Vestibulum rutrum nec nibh ac aliquet. Vestibulum lacus felis, vulputate et pretium eu, posuere euismod sapien. Sed varius vel sapien non dapibus. Nullam metus lectus,
      fringilla quis orci ac, iaculis consectetur ipsum. Curabitur magna purus, interdum non accumsan quis, bibendum euismod ante. Curabitur non suscipit ligula. Aliquam id leo ac dolor eleifend mattis. Maecenas neque dui, vestibulum vel massa nec, pharetra
      sagittis libero. Nunc sit amet aliquet arcu, tempor dapibus lectus. Suspendisse laoreet massa ac tortor egestas sollicitudin. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
  </div>
  <nav id="nav" aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li>
        <a href="#" aria-label="Previous" class="prev">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#" class="One">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Two">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Three">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Four">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Five">5</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" aria-label="Next" class="next">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**

```
var ArrayOfPages = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];
```

> This array is the name array of your webpages. What does that mean by example you have a webpage called One, Two...
>
> You place those names in the array.
>
> If the names don't match it won't open any webpages and also not make
>   the pages active because it don't find a match with the name of the
>   current page.

**EDIT 2**

I have created a [Github project](https://github.com/Steven0213/Back_and_next_nav) to create a demo.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your code works ok but it loads a DIV from a series of DIVS in the same page right? I need to navigate from one page to the next and they are different .html files. So to say, different links in a list. The thing with DIVS is that I can´t make a Gigantic single page with lot of different DIVS im looking for a simple menu that loads different html pages.

Comment: Yes because I taught that would be the best option. You have also less html pages then.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that is for a really big site, more than a thousand pages, when I put more than 3 pages on a HTML file it gets to around 5 mb and that is too much, makes the site really slow. The code I have now works for loading the first page (url) from the list but then it just stays there.  I think it has to do with adding the active tag to the actual page every time but i dont know how to do it, tried with some codes from here but not working. Thanks.

Comment: If you want I can change so it would load a new html page instead of hide an show a div

Comment: I will be very grateful to you for doing so. I have searched for some code similar to yours but using urls and cant find any. Thanks!

Comment: If have edited it. If you find this is the answer accept the answer then so it can help other people! If you have any more question just ask them.

Comment: The code is still for changing Divs. I was triying to use the code puting Iframes inside the divs so that i can use your code as a solution for navigate through a list of url links, but it seems theres an error because it dont load the next div and shows all the divs. You can see that when you click here in the Run Code Snippet button. I will try to work on your code to see if I can solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Now I have edited that you place the names of your pages in to the array. So it open a new page like you asked

Comment: Tried to implement the code but next and previous are not working and it dont select as active the current page.                                                                                                  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/da781b9dda8009e2473646cbd15ed264

Comment: See update. Did you know that? If not sorry It taught the name made it clear what is means. If you have any question just respond

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Appreciate it. I made a HTML page with your code, then i made five html pages named as the array: One, Two, Three... I linked the javascript in a file called array.js set up the nav with the names of the html files but the next and previous buttons dont go anywhere and there is no selection of the active page when I navigate using the buttons. Is there something missing in this code?                                https://gist.github.com/anonymous/056efc71934d4498771bddfa0f03817c

Comment: See update You had some mistakes in your files so I created a github project. If you have any more question just ask.

Comment: Thank you very much Steven! The github code works perfectly. It loads previous and next pages and tags the active one. I have marked your answer as correct. Just one question more: since I have lot of pages, hundreds in each section, its not practical to show all this in the pagination menu. Is there a way to hide all this pages and show just 10 for example? So that its like: << 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 >> and when the user reachs 10 it advances to the next 10. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes I will try to update the Github project and let you know!